# wpf binding in xmas updated but not in code behind

Tags: wpf, data-binding, code-behind

I have an ItemsCollection being bound to an array of objects like so:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="Graph" ItemsSource="{Binding MyData.ItemsData}">...
```

I want to be able to change the ItemsSource based on a button press so I moved it to code-behind like so:

```
Analyzer.Graph.SetBinding(ListView.ItemsSourceProperty, 
                new Binding { Source = MyViewModel.MyData.ItemsData });
```

My problem is that when setting the binding in code-behind, the data is not updated when it has changed, whereas it is when setting in xaml.

My data class looks like:

```
private DataFreq[] _itemsData;
public DataFreq[] ItemsData
{
    get { return _itemsData; }
    set
    {
        _itemsData = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("ItemsData");
    }
}
```

And is being set like this:

```
DataFreq[] tmpdata = new DataFreq[30];
...add data to tmpdata here
MyViewModel.MyData.ItemsData = data;
```

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Source` of a binding is the object hosting the property, not the property itself.

You want:

```
Analyzer.Graph.SetBinding(ListView.ItemsSourceProperty, 
            new Binding("ItemsData") { Source = MyViewModel.MyData });
```

However, since you already have an "ItemsData" property that notifies when it changes, then just change that rather than the binding. Bindings are just a way of coupling the view the the viewmodel. If the data source should change due to a button press, then the data source should change in the viewmodel, not the view.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Also, think this is a duplicate from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/357033/c-sharp-data-binding-doesnt-update-wpf?rq=1